# listings package introduces unnecessary linebreaks

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am using the listings package to include source code. This works pretty well, however, sometimes lines are broken, but the input does not continue on the following line, only the postbreak arrow is displayed.

It seems that the listings package calculates line breaks incorrectly or takes whatever is specified by postbreak into account. I already checked [the listings manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) but have not found a solution to this problem.

Minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newcent}

\usepackage{color} % requirement
\usepackage{listings} % reference source code
% a version without custom colors taken from classicthesis
\lstset{language=Haskell,%[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    morekeywords={PassOptionsToPackage,selectlanguage},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,%none
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    %frameround=ftff,
    frame=tb,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip,
    captionpos=b,
    literate={\>}{}{0\discretionary{>}{}{>}},
    %frame=L
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello World}
\section{Minimal Working Example}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \lstinline{all} do not use lambda functions.
\end{document}
```

Output is:

[image: Output of mwe.tex]

Comment: Make a complete example that we can test.

Comment: It's hard to help you without having some code to play with. Please provide us with a minimal, but working example (MWE).

Comment: I did :). Hope this is minimal enough and you (@ulrike-fischer  and @texnician) see the updated question.

Comment: It is not minimal enough as I had to comment out at least 15 options of `\lstset` to concentrate on problem. Anyway, the problem does not appear to show in this mwe if using `breakatwhitespace=true`, and the fact that it does with `breakatwhitespace=false` is probably  a bug. You should report to package maintainer.

Comment: @jfbu okay, I will report this. Thanks for your answer and for the time you invested.Unfortunately, ``breakatwhitespace=true`` alone is not an option, because then I get overlong lines.

Comment: The problem is that you actually have an overfull line and so listings inserts a discretionary. You could use microtype, or `\lstinline[brealines=false]{all}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there must be some problem with the way listings uses `\discretionary`, because the issue should definitely not occur. I suspect it adds the `\discretionary` after the last character wich does not make sense.

Comment: @jfbu Yes I just spoke with the maintainer and he knew about the problems with postbreak.

Comment: I never got around to report this, I was near the end of my thesis and then honestly forgot about it. [Now I only found the ctan page](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) and since @UlrikeFischer says this is known, I am going to leave this issue open, because it is not resolved. Thank you jfbu and UlrikeFischer for your help and your support!